# GD lib на PHP imagecreatefrom*()

Tags: php, nginx, битрикс, gd

при попытке создания картинки всегда возвращает false, указывал абсолютный и относительные пути, gd установлен, jpeg/png support =1 
кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Код:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('prodaga-page-img8.jpg');
var_dump($img);
```

Вот что возвращает gd_info()

```
Array
(
    [GD Version] => 2.2.5
    [FreeType Support] => 1
    [FreeType Linkage] => with freetype
    [T1Lib Support] => 1
    [GIF Read Support] => 1
    [GIF Create Support] => 1
    [JPEG Support] => 1
    [PNG Support] => 1
    [WBMP Support] => 1
    [XPM Support] => 1
    [XBM Support] => 1
    [WebP Support] => 1
    [JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] => 
)
```

---

Comment: добавьте в вопрос код.без него вам ничего не ответят. чем больше информации об окружении вы предоставите,тем выше ваши шансы получить ответ

Comment: благодарю, сейчас поправлю

Comment: в логах чего нить пишется? отображение ошибок включено? `error_get_last()` ? и да, пишите полный путь к фалу.

Comment: imagecreatefromjpeg(prodaga-page-img8.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory


|||||| как мне указать путь к файлу?

imagecreatefromjpeg(https://test.mos-nt.ru/prodaga-page-img8.jpg): failed to open stream: operation failed

Comment: абсолютный путь в вашей ФС указывайте `/var/www/site.ru/img/my-file.jpg` и т.п.

Comment: а откуда абсолютный путь отсчитывается?

Comment: от самого начала `/`. Как и в случае инклуда скрипта в вашем вопросе, возьмите документ-рут, и допишите к нему оставшийся путь до файла. Если конечно у вас пхп файл и картинка в одной директории, можете и просто имя указать.

Comment: в моем случае путь указываю так ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/prodaga-page-img8.jpg') - работает

Answer (score 0):

проблема решена, я сделал 2 ошибки
 1. не залил файл в директорию из которой брал картинку
 2. нужно указать путь вида ('./*.jpg') путь отсчитывается от расположения текущего php скрипта, либо так ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/prodaga-page-img8.jpg') - абсолютный путь 
 всем спасибо за помощь